# VueJS use NPM Component in Browser using Browserify

Tags: vue.js, browserify

I have a custom component in my page, defined as:

```
Vue.component('payment-page', {
    template: '#payment-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            ...
        }
    },
    components: {
        DatePicker
    },
});
```

Now, in this component, I need to use a datepicker/daterange picker, of which I found [this](https://mengxiong10.github.io/vue2-datepicker/) to be most helpful. It can be installed from NPM using `npm install vue2-datepicker --save`. I am using browserify so as to be able to use the datepicker in the browser, inside my component above.
For browserify, inside my *main.js* file I have this:

```
let DatePicker = require('vue2-datepicker');
```

then I use the command `browserify main.js -o bundle.js` to create my *bundle.js* file which I then import in my HTML file. 
Problem is I always get the error **Uncaught ReferenceError: DatePicker is not defined**. Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `payment-page` component also in `main.js`?

Comment: Nope, it's in a different file.

Comment: OK, you need to import it into each file you are using it in. You may also prefer to look at using [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) for this.